JEditorPane hangs when displaying HTML file containing COMBINING MACRON. Solutions?
Our XML Editor uses JEditorPane to display HTML transformed using stylesheet. When the incoming XML contains combing macron (for example, x̄), the system hangs during rendering in JEditorPane, though the producted HTML can be displayed in browser without any problem. It uses customized HTMLEditorKit with the JEditorPane. JDK 11 is currently used.
I have tried to replace the combing macron with the character reference &#x0304; in the XML.
textContent = textContent.replaceAll("\\u0304", "&#x0304;");

Original, \<p id="p0007" num="0007"\>LCL=x̄-(t\*(s /√n))；\</p\>
After, \<p id="p0007" num="0007"\>LCL=x&#x0304;-(t\*(s /√n))；\</p\>
But the system is still hanging when rendering in JEditorPane.
Any suggestion or advice would be highly appreciated.
Best,

I copied your text “LCL=x̄-(t*(s /√n))；” into a JEditorPane configured for HTML, without any additional setup, and it worked fine. So, to help us to help you: 1) Show the stack trace indicating that the code truly hangs at rendering this character 2) provide a [mre] including your JEditorPane initialization steps

Placing <p id="p0007" num="0007">LCL=x&#x0304;-(t*(s /√n))；</p> in a JEditorPane using Java 11 works fine for me.

Thanks to Holger and VGR for the answers. Following the hint, I have found the problem is caused by the customized HTMLEditorKit. For a quick fix for displaying the HTML without system hanging, I have added a switch to avoid to use the problematic customized editkit when a combing macron is identified:
private void setHtmlEditorContentType(String xmlText) {
    if (this.hasCombingMacro(xmlText) {
        //For handling tif images but may have performance issue            
        patchEditor = this.getPatchedHTMLEditorKit();       
        patchEditor.install(webBrowser);
        webBrowser.setEditorKitForContentType("text/html", patchEditor);
    }else {
        patchEditor.deinstall(webBrowser);
        webBrowser.setEditorKit(null);
        webBrowser.setContentType("text/html");
    }
}

//Check Combing Macro
private boolean hasCombingMacro(String xmlText) {
    if(xmlText.contains("\u0304") || xmlText.contains("&#x0304;")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

